# run exe on 1and 1 hosted site

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have a `ffmpeg.exe` file than runs on localhost but this doesn't work on my web server. As it is 1and1 I can't install `ffmpeg` as a extension. All this is supposed to do is create a thumbnail from the video in the same folder.

```
<?php
  $output = 'robot.jpg';
  $input = 'robot.avi';
  $ffmpegpath = "ffmpeg.exe";
  if(file_exists($ffmpegpath)){
    echo 'found the file <br/>';
  }
  $size = '100x100';
  $sec = '1';
  $cmd = "ffmpeg.exe -i $input -an -ss $sec -s $size $output";
  if(exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd))){
    echo 'worked';
  }else{
    echo 'not worked';
  }
?>
```

Is there a way of getting this too work without having full control over the server. The site is hosted on a basic lunix package, this was set up by a friend. So there isn't much control.

Comment: 1. You can't run .exe files on Linux and 2. If a hosting company allowed you to run random executables, you could hack them in seconds.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin many hosting sites allow you to run random executables, for instance through fcgi [of course, they sandbox you to death LOL]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run windows executables on Linux (unless you install something like Wine) but if you can install packages, you could install the linux version of ffmpeg for the distribution that your hosting service uses, see the [download page of ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html),

However, it seems unlikely that a basic hosting package would allow you to do that.